# Show that $\int_{1}^\infty |f(x)|^p \, \mathrm{d} x < \infty $ iff $ p = 2$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I am working through a Real Analysis textbook. The author gives the following example

> **Example 1:**  Define $ f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$  by 
>   $$ f(x) = \begin{cases}
> 0 & x \leq 1, \\
> \dfrac{x^{-1/2}}{ 1 + \ln x} & x> 1.
> \end{cases} $$
>   Then $\displaystyle \int_{1}^\infty |f(x)|^p \, \mathrm{d} x < \infty $ iff $ p = 2$.

I am not sure why this is the case. I imagine that you find a bound and use the comparison test. However, I am struggling to see what bound to use.

Comment: The author is wrong, I think. For $x > 1$ you have $\ln(x) > 0$ and so that you actually have $f(x)$ is bounded. So this means that if the integral converges for a certain $p$, it must also converge for all $q$ that is larger than $p$. The statement would be correct if $p = 2$ is replaced by $p  \geq 2$.

Comment: If you define $f(x)=\frac{x^{-1/2}}{1+ln(x)}$ and  $\int_0^\infty$ then it makes sense.  At $x=0$ it diverges for $p\gt 2$ while at the upper limit it diverges for $p\lt 2$.

Comment: @herbsteinberg: near $x=\frac1e$, we have $\frac1{|1+\log(x)|}\sim\frac1{|ex-1|}$ which is not in $L^p$ for $p\ge1$.

Comment: @robjohn I was ignoring what happened between the end points. How about $1+|log(x)|$ for the denominator?

Comment: @herbsteinberg: that works. In fact Michael Cook and I wrote that and the equivalent $\sqrt{\frac{x^{-1}}{1+\log(x)^2}}$ in comments to Divide1918's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $p\ne 2$, we may use integration by parts: $\int_1^{\infty} |f(x)|^p dx=\int_1^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{x^{p/2}(1+\ln x)^p}dx =\dfrac{x^{1-p/2}}{(1-p/2)(1+\ln x)^p}|_1^{\infty}+\int_1^{\infty}\dfrac{px^{1-p/2}}{(1-p/2)(1+\ln x)^{p+1}} dx$

Notice when we plug in the values, $\dfrac{x^{1-p/2}}{(1-p/2)(1+\ln x)^p}|_1^{\infty}=(\dfrac1{1-p/2}\lim_{t\to \infty}\dfrac{t^{1-p/2}}{(1+\ln t)^{p+1}})-(\dfrac1{1-p/2})$. The limit exists iff $1-p/2\le 0,$ i.e. $p\ge 2$.

For p=2, simply make a substitution as suggested by imranfat to get the antiderivative $-\dfrac1{1+\ln x}$. Plugging in the values, the improper integral is evaluated to be 1.

Conclusion: The improper integral exists whenever $p\ge 2$

Comment: What would happen if it was $|\ln x|$ instead of $\ln x$?

Comment: In the domain of integration, ln(x)>0

Comment: In the domain $ x > 0$

Comment: Then you may do similarly for integration over $x\in(0,1)$ to get a range for p.Then you take the intersection of the two ranges for p.

Comment: @MichaelCook: so $\frac{x^{-1/2}}{1+|\log(x)\,|}$? That looks good. I was thinking of $\sqrt{\frac{x^{-1}}{1+\log(x)^2}}$

Comment: You cannot split the absolute value like that if you want an equality. For 0<x<1, |1+log(x)|<=1+|log(x)|=1-log(x). 1+log(x)<0 => x<1/e, since on [1/e,1] which is a compact interval the integral clearly exists, we only have to consider $x\in (0,1/e)$, where |1+log(x)|=-(1+log(x))

Comment: @Divide1918: we are not trying to get the same answer. We are trying to modify the function so that it is in $L^p$ for $p=2$, but for no other $1\le p\le\infty$, because that is what the question mentions.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, for $p=2$ the integral can be evaluated. Substitute $1+lnx=t$ and you will end up with a constant in the numerator and a quadratic term in the denominator. Now it is standard. The fact that $x=1$ is not officially in the domain of the integral, can be dealt with through a limit